# TYPO3 News Extension, issue with tx_news.templateLayouts

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have made a top3 view of the news list. (se bottom) [www.codem.dk](http://www.codem.dk), i have a problem, and thats that it using my default list.html layout.

I have tried this, but i can't get it to work.

I have Templates/News/List.html and here i have this code. where I have the condition about the templateLayout = 99 and where i tell it to use Partials/List/ItemTop.html

```
{namespace n=Tx_News_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
=====================
Templates/News/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
<f:if condition="{news}">
<f:then>
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 99">
<f:then>
<ul>
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
<f:render partial="List/ItemTop" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
</f:for>
</ul>
</f:then>
<f:else>
<f:if condition="{settings.hidePagination}">
<f:then>
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
<f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
</f:for>
</f:then>
<f:else>
<n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}">
<div class="news-list-view">
<ul class="cbp_tmtimeline {newsItem.type}{f:if(condition: newsItem.istopnews, then: ' topnews')}">
<f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem">
<f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
</f:for>
</ul>
</div>
</n:widget.paginate>
</f:else>
</f:if>
</f:else>
</f:if>
</f:then>
<f:else>
<div class="no-news-found">
<f:translate key="list_nonewsfound" />
</div>
</f:else>
</f:if>
</f:section>
```

Then i have the Partials/List/ItemTop.html page, that have this code.

```
{namespace n=Tx_News_ViewHelpers}
<n:excludeDisplayedNews newsItem="{newsItem}" />
<li>
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}">
{newsItem.title}
</n:link>
<span class="post-date"><n:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{newsItem.datetime}</n:format.date></span>
</li>
```

Then I have this in my Page TS config code, on the hidden SYS folder, thats show the top3 news.

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
99 = Top 3 News layout
}
```

But i can see it's still using the layout code from the default Partials/List/Item.html page, whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, just let a template output

> {settings.templateLayout}

to see if it is really 99. I guess it is not. Did you only set the possibility to have a layout 99 in PageTS? Maybe you forgot to select this layout in the News Plugin.

Comment: Hi Lorenz. i followed the manual http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Templating/Additional/Index.html diden't see any place that i needed to select the template from the plugin/Template Tab and then "Template Layout" but i have selected the "Top 3 News layout" from that dropdown list now, and it's work.
Thx. but diden't see in the manual that i need that "step" to.